# How can I flag messages as "personal" via sieve?

Tags: thunderbird

I use sieve on the mailserver (dovecot) and thunderbird as mail user agent.

I want to flag messages which are from me as "personal".

High level use case: In long mailing-list discussion I want to see my mails fast.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file:

```
user@server> vi .dovecot.sieve
```

File content:

```
require "fileinto";
require "imap4flags";

if header :contains "from" "guettler" {
   addflag "$label3";
}
...
```

Related: [Pigeonhole Sieve examples - Flagging or Highlighting your mail | wiki2.dovecot.org](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Flagging_or_Highlighting_your_mail)